# DRY up jquery functions

Tags: jquery, dry

I have a form that has many select inputs that are grouped by theme.  I have a master select for each group that allows a user to set all selects in a group to the master value (gradescales is a method that provides grades 1-8).

How could I go about DRYing this up?

## FORM

```
<label>Change all to:</label>
<%= select_tag "section_one", options_for_select(gradescales), :id => "section_one_master" %>
    
    <div id="section_one_wrapper">
      <%= f.input :item_one,   :collection => gradescales %>
      <%= f.input :item_two,   :collection => gradescales %>
      <%= f.input :item_three, :collection => gradescales %>
      <%= f.input :item_four,  :collection => gradescales %>
    </div>
```

## jquery functions look like:

```
$("#section_one_master").change( function() { 
   var a = $("#section_one_master").val(); 
   $("#section_one_wrapper select").val(a);
 });

$("#section_two_master").change( function() { 
   var a = $("#section_two_master").val(); 
   $("#section_two_wrapper select").val(a);
 });    

 ...again, and again
```

So, when section_one_master is changed, the function is hit and all the select inputs inside the section_one_wrapper div are changed to match whatever value was chosen in the master.

I have many groups, each with a master select input.  How could I DRY this up to one function, and then dynamically id the master that called the function in the first place and use convention to change the appropriate grouped selected?

Comment: Use a class instead of id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add classes to your *master section* elements:

```
$(".section-masters").change( function() {  
    var id = this.id.replace('master', 'wrapper');   
    $('#' + id + " select").val(this.value);
});
```

Note that in the context of change handler `this` refers to the element, you don't have to reselect the element.

You can also select the *section wrapper* elements and cache the object and use `filter` method, by caching the object, you only select those elements once, which is better than re-selecting them.

```
var $wrappers = $('.section-wrappers');
//...
$wrappers.filter('[id="' + id + '"]').val(this.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, as @Blazemonger said you could use a class and it would help a lot

But you could also do this

```
var foos = ['one', 'two'];

$.each(foos, function(index, elem){
  var $selector = $("#section_" + elem + "_master");
  $selector.change( function() { 
   var a = $selector.val(); 
   $("#section_" + elem + "_wrapper select").val(a);
  });
});
```

But totally! If you can use a class do it!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a class and an id to each master and wrapped each section in an id.  Then in my coffee script:

```
  $(".master_change").change -> $("div##{@.id}_section select").val $(@).val()
```

The script is trigger by any .master_change, which grabs the id from 'this' that is then added to '_section' which grabs the wrapper for that sections selects...and then of course changes all of their values to match the master.  12 lines to one line!